# Why defaultValue is an empty Object?

Tags: reactjs

Why defaultValue is an empty Object?
When I console.log it I have {}.
What is the reason?

```
const App = () => {
  const [competitions, setCompetitions] = useState([]);
  const [defaultValue, setDefaultValue] = useState({})
    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/getCompetitions')
        .then(res => res.data)
        .then(res => {
          for(let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            competitions[i] = {
              "value": res[i].name,
              "label": res[i].name,
              "id": res[i]._id
            }
          };
          setCompetitions(competitions);
        })
        .then(() => setDefaultValue(competitions[0].value))
        .then(() => console.log(defaultValue))
    }, []);
```

Comment: Set state is asynchronous. It is done in batches and the mechanism is internal to react. You cannot expect it to work like a promise and the result will not be available in the then() block. Next render cycle will definitely have the right value

Answer (score 0):

As menthioned in the comment: 'Set state is asynchronous'.You're trying to access it before the state has actually been set. You can detect the value of `defaultValue` state in a separate useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(defaultValue))
   if(defaultValue) {
      // do something
   }
}, [defaultValue]);
```

Comment: So how can I rely on the fact that defaultValue in return will run correctly?                     
  return (
    <div>
      Hi
      <Competitions
        competitions = {competitions}
        defaultValue = {defaultValue}
      />
    </div>
  )

Comment: you can enclose you UI componet with a condition to check if defaultValue has a valid value or not. Initialize defaultValue with null and then apply a check like this: {defaultValue && return ( <div> Hi <Competitions competitions = {competitions} defaultValue = {defaultValue} /> </div> )}